# Auto increment column in delta table without rekey

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I have a dim delta table so far i am calculating `dim_id` using `row_number() + max(dim_id)`.

```
Dim_id | user_id

1001   |   1
1002   |   3
1003   |   5
1004   |   9
```

For example if i deleted 1004 id then insert a new user_id like 7 `(row_number() + max(dim_id) = 1004)` 1004 id repeated. Is there any way to prevent already used ids not created once it deleted from the delta table

Answer (score 2):

- The perfect way to solve this is `Primary Key`, yet not support until now.
- You can combine `monotonically_increasing_id()` with `row_number()` for two columns. Here is the example: [Generate unique increasing values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/sql/gen-unique-increasing-values#combine-monotonically_increasing_id-with-row_number-for-two-columns)

RD：

1. [monotonically_increasing_id()](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/monotonically_increasing_id.html)
2. [Constraints on Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/tables/constraints.html)